# RxJava2 subscribe method dont update mutable livedata

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I use RxJava2 and I need to update some logs after process is done. Logs are mutable livedata.

In `subscribe (onSuccess)` method I have some assigments and also calling a method that post to livedata. But problem is, it doesnt **post** values to **livedata**. Timber command executes fine.

```
// rx stuff
.subscribe({ success ->
   // ...assigments
   controllerLocation = success
   connectionText.postValue("Connected!")

   // PROBLEM - post livedata
   logUpdate("Done")
   logUpdate("Changing communication speed")

   // ...other methods which are executed fine
   otherMethod1()
   otherMethod2()
}, { error ->
   printError(error)
})

// logsUpdate method that post to livedata
private fun logUpdate(update: String) {
    val string = update + '\n' + '\n'
    logs.postValue(string + logs.value.orEmpty())
    Timber.i(update)
}
```

I except **updated livedata** cause I need to print new logs to screen.
I also try `livedata.setValue(value)`, but it also didnt work.
Timber commands are just for debug.

I use method `logsUpdate(...)` often in others subscribe methods and it works.

Comment: is your livedata object `observe`d by somebody?

Comment: Yes, right from XML textview via databinding

Comment: Are you connecting your ViewModel to your xml and binding.setLifeCycleOwner(this) in the activity

Comment: `postValue` is recommended to be used in background thread.. use `setValue` to set value from UI thread

Comment: I also try setValue, didnt work as I mentioned in questions

Comment: Yes, by: binding.lifecycleOwner = this

Comment: @SantanuSur was right, postValue only accept last value in process